# Crashes with android app 1.0.68

Tags: bug, android-app

The new version of the android app 1.0.68 has a serious problem.  I can look at my first site just fine (say ask ubuntu for example).  When I go back to the main page/intro screen, it looks fine too.  When I touch a 2nd group (android enthusiasts for example) I get the list of questions displayed OK.  But when I touch a question, I get the main page/intro screen mixed up with the question screen, and the app crashes.

I reverted to version 1.0.63 and it works fine.

Android 4.2.2

Comment: You are correct, it is a duplicate.  Thanks for pointing that out.  My device is the world's lowest end tablet, an Azpen A727.

Comment: There's one difference, mine is crashing on 5.1.1 tablet, while a smartphone with 4.4.2 is ok.

Comment: Maybe a tablet thing then?